# SwiftUI: Increase icon button hitbox (ignoring horizontal safe space)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to increase the hitbox of a Navbar button with an SF Symbol icon as it's contents.

```swift
NavigationView {
Text("Example")
.navigationBarTitle("Tasks").navigationBarItems(trailing:

                Button(action: openModal) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus").padding(EdgeInsets(top: 50, leading: 50, bottom: 50, trailing: 0)).background(Color.black).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all).font(.system(size: 30))
                })

}
```

However, when I show the set the background of the icon to black, the part of the area that is shown as the hitbox is not clickable (red box below), and the side of the hitbox that hits the horizontal safe zone won't expand its hitbox to include the safe zone (pink box below).

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. No matter if I use .frame(width: 50, height: 50) or .padding(EdgeInsets) only the horizontal (width) touchable area of the button is extended not the vertical (height).

Comment: See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-the-tappable-area-of-a-view-using-contentshape